# In which vs whose

Tags: grammar

> I read a novel (in which - whose) the main character is a kid.

I've been told by a friend to choose whose in case absence of *the* in this sentence. Is the correct answer **in which**?

Answer (score 2):

To be really persnickety, "who," "whom," and "whose" refer to people. So I personally would write "... a novel in which the main character is ...".

Many people, however, are less persnickety than I am and would substitute "whose" for "in which." In that case, the definite article would disappear. Possesive pronouns replace articles, "his shoes," "her dress," "their dinner," and "whose main character." If you recognize that "whose" is a possesive pronoun meaning "belonging to whom," you will recognize the application of a general rule.

But, to repeat, I would not use "whose" in the first place.

Comment: I'm afraid that "persnickety" here means "wrong". There are and have been people who insist that "whose" can refer only to people: they are ignorant of both the realities of English usage (as used by a wide range of well-regarded authors) and of history. "Whose" derives from the Old English _hwas_, which was the genitive of both _hwá_ ('who') and _hwæt_ ('what').. The OED gives examples of "whose" with an inanimate antecedent from 1382 to 1981. You are, of course, free not to use it that way yourself, but there is nothing wrong with it.